# Delete a range of columns using two named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I need to delete a range of rows using two named ranges

Current find the column numbers for the last column (lastColumn) and then the column 6 spots behind it (colrange)

```
Dim lastColumn As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
colrange = lastColumn - 6
```

I want to delete the columns in the range colrange:lastColumn but not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range(Cells(1,colRange),Cells(1,lastColumn)).EntireColumn.Delete`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use:

```
Range(Columns(colRange),Columns(lastColumn)).Delete
```

or directly:

```
With ActiveSheet
  .Range(.Columns(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 6), .Columns(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Delete
End With
```